# Вернуть значение из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица(Table) с полями (Name, age)
1. Нужно проверить существование записи в таблице по имени. Если запись не найдена вернуть 0. Если найдена значение из колонки "age". Подскажите как это сделать в ms sql server.

нашел как проверить существование записи, а вот как вернуть значение не могу сообразить.

```
IF(Select top 1 [age]
   From Table
   Where Name = 'user_name') IS NULL
begin
select 'not found'
end
else
begin
select //значение возраста
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы получить строго одну запись, подойдет использование агрегатной функции (с неявной группировкой), которая при этом вернет NULL, в случае если записи нет. NULL преобразуется в любое требуемое значение с использованием функции coalesce:

```
select coalesce(max(age), 0)
  from Table
 where Name = 'user_name'
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно.